# Send byte array and derserialize it as Avro record with kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm sending byte array corresponding to Avro Record to kafka.

The producer:

```
props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker-address");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "Kafka Avro ClientOrderRequest Producer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "schema-registry address");

KafkaProducer<String, ClientOrderRequest> producerRequest = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        
while (true) {
    ClientOrderRequest clientOrderRequest = createClientOrderRequest();
    byte[] bytes = toByteArray(clientOrderRequest);
    final ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> producerOrderRequest = new ProducerRecord<>("client-order-request",
                "ClientOrderRequest-" + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), bytes);
    producerRequest.send(producerOrderRequest);
    producerRequest.flush();
    System.out.println("Produced 1 record.");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

The consumer:

```
props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker-address");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
props.put("schema.registry.url", "schema-registry address");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "events-group-3");

KafkaConsumer<String, ClientOrderRequest> clientOrderRequestConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        clientOrderRequestConsumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("client-order-request"));

while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, ClientOrderRequest> records = clientOrderRequestConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, ClientOrderRequest> record : records) {
        String key = record.key();
        ClientOrderRequest value = record.value();
            System.out.println(key);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The producer is able to send the byte array to the topic. But the Consumer isn't able to deserialize it. I have the error:

> B cannot be cast to com.swissquote.eforex.generated.avro.trading.ClientOrderRequest

A client-order-request-value subject is registered on the schema registry when I produce the message.
I understand that I send a byte array and that the kafka/schema-registry expect an Avro record but I would have expect it would be able to deserialize it.

If it's not possible using the simple AvroKafkaSerializer should I implement my own serializer ?

Answer (score 0):

What is `toByteArray`?

You don't need to manually serialize your data. That's the whole point of the serializer class. Unclear why you've changed this from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71936729/2308683)

```
ClientOrderRequest clientOrderRequest = createClientOrderRequest();
final ProducerRecord<String, ClientOrderRequest> producerOrderRequest = new ProducerRecord<>("client-order-request",
                "ClientOrderRequest-" + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), clientOrderRequest);
producerRequest.send(producerOrderRequest);
producerRequest.flush();
```

When you send a byte array with KafkaAvroSerializer.class, it sends an Avro object of `{"type": "bytes"}`, not your custom record

If you really want to send byte arrays directly, you would use `ByteArraySerializer`, but this would bypass the schema registry

Comment: toByteArray just take my AvroRecord and transform it to byte array.

I know I don't need to do it, but in my case i'm receiving byte[] of which I know the corresponding avro schemas. So I wanted to send thos bytes without having to serialize it but when I read it from the other side, I can have them in their AvroRecord form.